# Placement of --include list in zip

Tags: zip

When I execute the command

```
zip -r --include '*.rb' '*.sh' '*.zsh' '*irb*' tmp/small_v.zip bin
```

I get the error message *zip error: Invalid command arguments (nothing to select from)*

If I write the command as

```
zip -r tmp/small_v.zip bin --include '*.rb' '*.sh' '*.zsh' '*irb*'
```

it works. Why? Looking at the zip man page (in particular, the --include option), I find:

*Though the command syntax used to require -i at the end  of  the              command  line,  this  version  **actually allows -i (or --include)               anywhere**.  The list of files terminates  at  the  next  argument              starting with -, the end of the command line, or the list 
terminator @ (an argument that is just @).*

From this, I would have concluded that both versions of the command should work.

I'm using zip 3.0 running on MacOS Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part in this case is

> The list of files terminates at the next argument starting with `-`, the end of the command line, or the list terminator `@` (an argument that is just `@`).

When you write

```
zip -r --include '*.rb' '*.sh' '*.zsh' '*irb*' tmp/small_v.zip bin
```

`tmp/small_v.zip` and `bin` are treated as files given to `--include`, so the `zip` command ends up with no target file and no files to process.

`--include` *can* be placed anywhere, but its arguments still have to make sense, and the remaining arguments have to be identifiable. You could write your command as

```
zip --include '*.rb' '*.sh' '*.zsh' '*irb*' -r tmp/small_v.zip bin
```

instead, using the `-r` parameter to identify the end of the list of files for `--include`, or use `@` to terminate the list:

```
zip -r --include '*.rb' '*.sh' '*.zsh' '*irb*' @ tmp/small_v.zip bin
```

There are very similar examples at the end of the `--include` section in [the `zip(1)` manpage](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zip.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

its a bit weird and i didn`t make deep research but i needed to use

`zip -r --include="server_*" ...`

to include files starting with sth to make this working on a CI/CD setup